# Android App Not Install. An existing package by the same name

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have lost my old debug.keystore file and i generated a new one, when i build my new apk and i want to update the old one in my phone it show me "Android App Not Install. An existing package by the same name".

Can any one help me what should i do? can i modify the debug.keystore with the old  sha1 ???

Answer (score 6):

> Can any one help me what should i do?

Uninstall the existing app.

> can i modify the debug.keystore with the old sha1 ?

No.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to publish an update on Google Play if the app is signed by a different keystore than the one first published. You'll need to change the package name, resulting in a new app on Google Play.

If the old app isn't published just go ahead and uninstall the old app to be able to install the new.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had Shared the steps, It will definitely resolve the issue regarding Unity Android App Not Installed

1. UnInstall Existing App
2. Check is you bundle identifier is same with previous build
3. PlayerSettings > Enable build il2cpp Armv7 and 64bit build and donot split the build
4. Assign the keystore and assign password
5. Set the player setting SDK Card to Automatic
6. Make Sure your previous build is assigned with same keystore
7. Target Api Level should be Equal or greater than previous one